# No response from [ -f /path/to/file ]

Tags: bash, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am trying to get my Capistrano deploy script working, but it is not doing the symlinking as it is configured to do as shown below.

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp vendor/bundle public/system}
```

When it runs the related command, I get the following:

```
WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env [ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ]
```

If I run this command on the server, either through ssh or through logging onto the server and running the command, I get no response from the command.

```
user: ~
$ [ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ]
user: ~
$
```

The file does exist in the specified location and has permissions.

```
user: ~
$ ll /path/to/shared/config/
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 user group  33 Nov 30 10:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 user group  89 Nov 30 10:58 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user group 805 Nov 30 10:58 database.yml
user: ~
```

Shouldn't this return a true or a false, instead of nothing? Is there a configuration I may have changed that suppresses the output? I get no response at all whether the file exists or not.

Comment: Try adding the flags "-xv"'after the shebang line at the top of your script, i.e. #!/usr/bin/bash -xv

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a part of a Capistrano deploy script, so I don't think I can add that.

Comment: `[ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ]` would not provide output. It would return `1` for false and `0` for true. Run `echo $?` after `[ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ]` to see the return code

Comment: I see. I assumed it would output true/false or 1/0 in the log or when I run it. I misunderstood what it was doing, I think. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your full deploy config?  I suspect that you aren't using the app role (which seems to be a bug in that it's required for linked_dirs, linked_files)... see: https://github.com/wecapslabs/capistrano/commit/2fe6bebe4a1536e2f4ccb0ef8402ff1555a8bf06

Answer (score 0):

In your response to the actual question you ask, `test` (which is what `[` is an alias for) does in fact *not* return output to stdout.  It returns an exit code.

```
user: ~
$ [ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ] # if the file exists
user: ~
$ echo $?
0

user: ~
$ [ -f /path/to/shared/config/database.yml ] # if the file does not exist
user: ~
$ echo $?
1
```

`test -f /path/to/file` (or `[ -f /path/to/file ]`) yields an exit code of `0` if the file exists or `1` if it does not.  If you want to check that a file is there and echo the path to it, try:

```
[ -f /path/to/file ] && echo "/path/to/file"
```